# Cannot read cookies set by ios from rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, react-native

I am using [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies). I can use the getAll method to read cookies that have been previously set on the server side. In react native I can use the set command to set a cookie called 'myCookie', and I can read it using the getAll command. However, I cannot read a cookie on the server side that has been set by the react-native app.

The react-native code which is in `index.ios.js`

```
var CookieManager = require('react-native-cookies')
  componentWillMount () {
    CookieManager.set({
      name: 'myCookie',
      value: 'myValue',
      domain: 'ios app',
      origin: 'some origin',
      path: '/',
      version: '1',
      expiration: '2017-05-30T12:30:00.00-05:00'
    }, (err, res) => {
      console.log('cookie set!');
      console.log(err);
      console.log(res);
      console.log('my output');
    });
    CookieManager.getAll((cookie) => {
      let isAuthenticated;
      if (cookie && cookie.remember_token) {
        isAuthenticated = true;
      }
      else {
        isAuthenticated = false;
      }

      this.setState({
        loggedIn: isAuthenticated
      });
      console.log('GM:cookie remember isAuthenticated', cookie.remember_token, isAuthenticated,this.state.title,'myCookie',cookie.myCookie)
    });
  },
```

The output from the last console log message is

```
GM:cookie remember isAuthenticated Object {domain: "localhost", value: "BAhbB2kHSSJFZmM3NDVkNTEwZTBkYTViZjU4NTJhOGQyZDNlMz…wY6BkVU--5888c15b42c6bdf3ca34c89f6554d2455d48c46b", name: "remember_token", path: "/"} true Sign In myCookie Object {domain: "ios app", value: "myValue", name: "myCookie", path: "/"}
```

showing that the myCookie object is being set and that the app is able to recover the remember_token set by the rails server.

The above code is executed at start up of the ios app. The ios app then opens a webview component that calls the new method in the sessions controller of a ruby on rails web app.  In the rails sessions controller, I find that `cookie['myCookie']` is `nil`.  Why is the cookie being set in a way that I cannot access it from the rails app?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to debug this partly verbal description of your code... could you provide us with code samples for "working" vs "not working examples? It'll help us better understand what you're doing and then we can better know what to ask for to help you figure it out.

Comment: I have added code as requested by Taryn East.

Comment: what if you remove, domain, origin, path, and version?

Comment: I cannot just remove them, because I get an error from react-native-cookie e.g. key domain cannot be nil. I tried setting all of them to an empty  string, but that did not allow the cookie to be viewed from the rails controller. I also tried setting the domain to the correct value, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies/issues/33) about this on the react-native-cookie github site on July 5, 2016 and have received no answer. The lack of response and other similar issues raised on the site makes me believe that at this time, react-native-cookie simply does not support this functionality.  This is not a criticism of the react-native-cookie team, any open source project has to draw the line somewhere.